# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Tags: java, ioexception

My code goes like this:

```
URL url;
URLConnection uc;
StringBuilder parsedContentFromUrl = new StringBuilder();
String urlString="http://www.example.com/content/w2e4dhy3kxya1v0d/";
System.out.println("Getting content for URl : " + urlString);
url = new URL(urlString);
uc = url.openConnection();
uc.connect();
uc.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
int ch;
while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
    parsedContentFromUrl.append((char) ch);
}
System.out.println(parsedContentFromUrl);
```

However when I am trying to access the URL through browser there is no problem , but when I try to access it through a java program, it throws expection:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add the code below in between `uc.connect();` and `uc.getInputStream();`:

```
uc = url.openConnection();
uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

However, it a nice idea to just allow certain types of user agents. This will keep your website safe and bandwidth usage low.

Some possible bad 'User Agents' you might want to block from your server depending if you don't want people leeching your content and bandwidth. But, user agent can be spoofed as you can see in my example above.

Comment: A good explanation of this question would be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619746/why-should-i-access-a-url-using-a-user-agent)

Comment: I had same problem for getting web page content. This solved my problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

403 means forbidden. From [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):-

> 10.4.4 403 Forbidden
>
> The server understood the request, but
>   is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the
>   request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the
>   request method was not HEAD and the
>   server wishes to make public why the
>   request has not been fulfilled, it
>   SHOULD describe the reason for the
>   refusal in the entity. If the server
>   does not wish to make this information
>   available to the client, the status
>   code 404 (Not Found) can be used
>   instead.

You need to contact the owner of the site to make sure the permissions are set properly.

**EDIT** I see your problem. I ran the URL through Fiddler. I noticed that I am getting a 407 which means below. This should help you go in the right direction.

> 10.4.8 407 Proxy Authentication Required
>
> This code is similar to 401
>   (Unauthorized), but indicates that the
>   client must first authenticate itself
>   with the proxy. The proxy MUST return
>   a Proxy-Authenticate header field
>   (section 14.33) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the proxy for the
>   requested resource. The client MAY
>   repeat the request with a suitable
>   Proxy-Authorization header field
>   (section 14.34). HTTP access
>   authentication is explained in "HTTP
>   Authentication: Basic and Digest
>   Access Authentication"

Also see this relevant question.

- [java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869372/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-403-for-url)

Comment: Mr coolbeans, thanks for the prompt response I saw few articles on web which say like what u ve mentioned but is there any solution to this i mean if the content was forbidden why my browser is able to access the URL? thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

IF the browser can access the page, and your code cannot, then there's something different between the browser request and your request. You can look at the browser request, using, say, Firebug, to see what the differences are. Some things I can think of are:

- The site sets a
  cookie (maybe during login). You may be able to handle
  this in code, you will have to
  explicitly add support for passing
  the cookie. This is most likely.
- The site filters based on user agents. You can set the user agent. This is not as likely.