# IOException - XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I am trying to parse an xml response from the below url -

```
http://imdbapi.org/?type=xml&q=argo
```

For this, i have written the below code -

```
    try
    {
        XMLReader myReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        xmlHandler handlerobj = new xmlHandler();
        myReader.setContentHandler(handlerobj);
        myReader.parse(new InputSource(new URL("http://imdbapi.org/?type=xml&q=argo").openStream()));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

xmlHandler is a class that extends DefaultHandler.
I am getting an **IOException** in the above code.

Stack trace -

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:   http://imdbapi.org/?type=xml&q=argo
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at gui.getimdbdata(gui.java:73)
at gui.main(gui.java:64)
```

What is the problem with this code ?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the Exception please?

Comment: Added the stack trace.

Comment: The server refuses to allow the requested action ([response code: 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403))
Everything is ok, with server configuration? Are you able to get the xml file in other ways?

Comment: I have a similar android project which does the same, parses the xml response from this same URL. I can see the xml using the browser too.

Comment: Why would it stop Java from doing the same ?

Comment: This url acceps only requests from browser. You can find solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797593/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-403-for-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, thanks to @dijkstra !

The web service would only allow browser to fetch the xml data.

Following are the modifications -

```
       url = new URL(urlString);
       uc = url.openConnection();
       uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");

       uc.connect();
       uc.getInputStream();
       BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set the user.agent:

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
```

(if you connect to the URL with your browser this is done automagically)