# Handling response code: 403 for URL with clojure enlive

Tags: java, http, clojure, http-status-code-403, enlive

I am trying to scrape content of a web page using enlive's html-resource function, but I am getting response 403, because I am not coming from a browser.I guess this can be overridden in Java (found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797593/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-403-for-url)) , but I would like to see a clojure way to handle this issue. Perhaps this can be achieved by providing parameters to html-resource function, but I have not encountered an example of how and what needs to be passed as parameter. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Properly you need something like clj-http or http-kit that allows you to have control of the connection where you can provide some settings, get the response and feed to (html-resource)

Comment: html-resource is a multimethod where you can pass a URL object to it. https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/blob/master/src/net/cgrand/enlive_html.clj#L112    This is a good point where you can set 'user-agent' to your URL connection object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enlive's `html-resource` does not provide a way to override the default request properties. You can, like the other answer you found, open the connection yourself and pass the resulting `InputStream` to `html-resource`.

Something like the following would handle it:

```
(with-open [inputstream (-> (java.net.URL. "http://www.example.com/")
                            .openConnection
                            (doto (.setRequestProperty "User-Agent"
                                                       "Mozilla/5.0 ..."))
                            .getContent)]
  (html-resource inputstream))
```

Although, it might look better split out into its own function.