# 403 Error code when downloading an image

Tags: java, http, curl, https

I'm trying to download an image using Java, however a 403 error code is returned:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://someurl.com

I've used the command curl with the same URL and it returns OK

```
curl -I https://someurl.com
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 11 Apr 2017 18:36:49 GMT Content-Type:
>   image/png Content-Length: 4233029 Connection: keep-alive

This is the code I'm using to download the images:

```
private static boolean downloadImage(String imageURL, String path)
{
    InputStream in;

    try 
    {            
        URL url = new URL(imageURL);

        in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        Files.copy(in, Paths.get(path), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.toString());

        return false;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.toString());

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any idea of why it fails with Java but it does work with the `curl` command?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869372/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-403-for-url?rq=1)

Comment: if possible paste your url, maybe need set some header, for instance, `User-Agent`.

Comment: @neuo How do I set the User-Agent with the method I'm using? Do I have to change the way I download the images?

Comment: @cuoka You can get image with curl, which confirm the url is accessible. You can read the link appeared in first comment, it may be helpful.